# Multiple for loop in C++

Tags: c++11, for-loop

I am trying to write current time and some data (distance & amplitude) from a sensor in a text file. Number of data are very large (sensor rotate at 50Hz frequency and number of data could be 5000 per scan). Now I want write current time first and then all the data in a single line like this,

```
11:23:17 (time)  
distance1 amplitude1; distance2 amplitude2; ... distance5000 amplitude5000;  
11:23:18  
distance1 amplitude1; distance2 amplitude2; ... distance5000 amplitude5000;  
.  
.  
.
11:27:00  
distance1 amplitude1; distance2 amplitude2; ... distance5000 amplitude5000;
```

"So my question is how to get this?"
I am able to write only distance and data like below

```
for(int t=0; t<distances.size(); t++)
 {
    pfsave << distances[t] <<"\t" << amplitudes[t]<<";";
 }
 pfsave<<endl;
```

Note: data type of distances & amplitudes are

```
vector<uint32_t> distacnes;
vector<uint32_t> amplitudes;
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: I suggest not writing `endl` when you want to place all data on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the current time like this, before the beginning of your for loop:

```
auto t = std::time(nullptr);
auto tm = *std::localtime(&t);
pfsave  << std::put_time(&tm, "%H:%M:%S") << std::endl;
```

Then your for loop without `endl`, to write a single line:

```
for(int t=0; t<distances.size(); t++)
{
    pfsave << distances[t] <<"\t" << amplitudes[t]<<";";
}
```

And finally add `endl`, to finish the line:

```
pfsave << endl;
```

---

EDIT: following your comment

```
bool canContinue = true; // Condition used to stop the loop when needded
while(canContinue)
{
    // Read data from your scanning device
    distances  = ... ;
    amplitudes = ... ;

    // Write output file
    auto t = std::time(nullptr);
    auto tm = *std::localtime(&t);
    pfsave  << std::put_time(&tm, "%H:%M:%S") << std::endl;

    for(int t=0; t<distances.size(); t++)
        pfsave << distances[t] <<"\t" << amplitudes[t]<<";";
    pfsave << endl;

    // Update of canContinue
    canContinue = ... ;
}
```

Comment: The thing is if I do this, it will only write one line (all the data only from one scan) and then it'll stop. I want to write data continuously.

Comment: Then you need to put all this in a `while` or a `for` loop, grabbing `distances` and `amplitudes` in each iteration.

Comment: I tried while loop and my programs went infinite loop.

Comment: If I try `for` loop it will write the same data again and again.

Comment: About the infinite loop: you need to define a stop condition (maybe a signal from your scanning device, or a button in a GUI, it's up to you).

About writing the same data, you need to refresh your arrays from the scanning device. You should look at examples from its manufacturer, or from the SDK if you're using one.